# How do I prevent a Windows program started with process:Command from opening a popup?

Tags: windows, rust

I run an executable like this:

```
let output = Command::new("executable_file")
                    .args( &["-path", path] ).output()?;
//do stuff with output...
```

Sometimes an error occurs and the executable will report an error which will cause a Windows error popup that will need to be closed by the user.

Is there a way to prevent Windows popups or just close any popups that do appear and continue?

Currently my program will just sit there waiting for the user to close the popup...

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just kill the command process if an error popup did open.

I did this by using `spawn()` which will create a child process, allowing me to continue executing my code after I have started running the .exe and then just error handle it so if the executable hangs due to the pop up(you can tell it will hang after a specific amount of time has passed) then just kill the child process...